# Parameter does not have a match; SimpleXML

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I am using `retrofit` with the `SimpleXMLConverterFactory`.

And I always get an

```
ConstructorException: Parameter 'success' does not have a match in class ResponseInfo
```

And I have no idea what could be wrong. The xml is very simple and i only want the string from the `success` node.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <success>LoremIpsum</success>
</response>
```

ResponseInfo:

```
@Root(strict = false, name = "response")
data class ResponseInfo(@Element(required = false, name = "success) var success: String)
```

Edit 1: I tested the Api call and it returns the given xml.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So finally, I managed to solve the problem myself.

The problem was the `ResponseInfo` class. After I changed it to

```
@Root(strict = false, name="response")
data class ResponseInfo @JvmOverloads constructor(
  @field:element(name = "success") var success: String = ""
)
```

all worked fine.

You need to have an empty constructor, all properties must be mutable (`var`) and you have to append `field:` in front of the `@Element`-Annotation. `@JvmOverloads` combined with default values will create the empty constructor for you as well as all other constructor variations.

Comment: upper case Element.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to avoid having a deafult constructor, you would have to use both `field` and `param` [use-site target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)s. It would look something like this:

```
@Root(strict = false, name = "response")
data class ResponseInfo(
    @field:Element(name = "success") @param:Element(name = "success") var success: String
)
```

As stated in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082194/is-it-possible-to-apply-a-single-annotation-to-multiple-use-site-targets-in-kotl#comment81124803_47082194) it seems like there isn't any way of combining the two use-site targets.